# pytest: avoiding long iteration over same datastructure in multiple tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Part of my test functions are iterating over quite large collection.

e.g:

```
def test_A(fixture):
    for elem, elem_data in fixture.items():
        <do stuff>
    assert ...

def test_B(fixture):
    for elem, elem_data in fixture.items():
        <do stuff>
    assert ...
```

I don't want to unify them in order to keep readability and reporting of distinct use cases, but I do want to get rid of the repeated iteration somehow and optimize running time.
**Any suggestions?**

Additional data:
The fixture(data structure) is the same in all the tests mentioned above.
Each test validates another (business logic related) aspect of the nested data structure. 
Example for *do stuff* would be: another nested for -> then check if some element is not contained in another list.

Comment: Is it _necessary_ to iterate over the entire collection? I.e., will the test be incomplete or invalid if you stop at 100?

Comment: Yes full iteration is part of the test

Comment: There is too little information: Do the fixtures hold the same elements?  Are there common operations in <do stuff> for A and B?  Having the loop in the test gives the impression that you execute the SUT within the <do stuff> - is this correct?

Comment: Hi @DirkHerrmann thank you for taking the time to comment. I've added the missing information to the question.

Comment: @Vano, you can see if it is possible to pre-process the data structure. For example, before the tests start, you could iterate over the entire collection and prepare some smaller/aggregated data set(s) which can be directly used or easily iterated over in the tests.

Comment: @yeniv nice one thanks! I'll try to and update

Comment: another interesting direction is https://pypi.org/project/pytest-subtests/
I'll check it as well and update

Comment: Hi Vano, thank you for updating the question.  Do I understand correctly that each of your tests checks the fixture variable if it fulfills some criterion?

Comment: @DirkHerrmann Yes. that variable comply with some business logic. For example if it contains one of items defined in another variable(list) in same fixture.

Comment: Is iterating over fixture.items() an expensive process (like reading from disk, db or network)? If it is, use a session scoped fixture to calculate everything in the beginning and hold it in memory and perform iteration.

If you want to just get rid repeated iterations, change to your fixture to take a function as an argument and run that function on all items. And change your <do stuff> into a function.
def test_A(fixture):
        def do_stuff():
              <do stuff>
        fixture(do_stuff)
        assert ...

@pytest.fixture
def fixture(a,b,func):
      return func(a,b)

Comment: @SilentGuy please consider posting as an answer so I can accept and other user will able to easily find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is iterating over fixture.items() an expensive process (like reading from disk, db or network)? If it is, use a session scoped fixture to calculate everything in the beginning and hold it in memory and perform iteration. If you want to just get rid repeated iterations, change your fixture to take a function as an argument and run that function on all items. And change your  into a function.

```
def test_A(fixture):
    def do_stuff():
        <do stuff> 
    fixture(do_stuff)
    assert ... 

@pytest.fixture
def fixture(a,b,func):
    return func(a,b)
```